# Create a Div that appears at the bottom of a page & closes on click using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have been trying to create a div that appears when a user scrolls to a certain height above the bottom of the page-- and can then be closed by clicking a close button.

In order to facilitate the animation of this div (the appearing and closing on click)  I am using two jquery functions:

**here is the first function:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$(window).scroll(function() {
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 900) {
$('.bpop-res').fadeIn();
}
});
});
```

which makes the div appear a certain height above the bottom of the page

**Here is the second function:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('#bpop-close').live('click', function(event) {        
jQuery('.bpop-res').toggle('hide');
});
});
```

to close the div on click of a button.

While each of these functions work fine individually on separate pages,  I can't seem to get them to work together on the same page.

Here is a [fiddle with both functions](http://jsfiddle.net/pvijeh/7ap5tsj7/1/)-- you'll notice that only the first one (the function that makes the div appear on scroll) works

Here is a [fiddle with only the close on click function.](http://jsfiddle.net/pvijeh/gejmmvn1/)  You'll notice that it works fine here.

I am pretty new to jquery and programming in general-- so is there anything obvious that I have done wrong here when trying to combine these two functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue was that you were using the keyword 'jquery' instead of '$'. 
[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nischaalc/7ap5tsj7/2/) should work for both functions!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var closed = false;
    $(window).scroll(function () {

        if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 900) {
            if (closed === false) $('.bpop-res').fadeIn();
        }
    });
    $('#bpop-close').click(function () {
        $('.bpop-res').hide();
        closed = true;
    });
});
```

I also added a condition to ensure that the box remains closed after it's been closed once, but you can remove this if you want.

Comment: No problem @psvj! Make sure you choose an accepted answer - either mine or the one that Alexdn posted :)

Comment: Just note that the variable `closed` permanently hides the `.bpop-res`.

Comment: Oh I missed it...sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `jquery` to `$`...
Change your code to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function() {
       if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 900) {
           $('.bpop-res').fadeIn();
       }
    });
    $('#bpop-close').click(function(event) {        
         $('.bpop-res').toggle('hide');
    });
});
```

Just edit your JSFiddle...

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. just remove the jQuery with $ sign.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(window).scroll(function() {
       if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 900) {
           $('.bpop-res').fadeIn();
       }
    });
    $('#bpop-close').on('click', function(event) {     //Change .live() to .on()
        alert("hide");
         $('.bpop-res').hide();
    });
});
```